# Who was the father of Rav Aha Bar Rav?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rabbis, amoroim

Rav Aha Bar Rav was a talmid-haver of Ravina (6th generation of amoraïm), and also a contenporary of Ravina II (7th) ([source](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%90/%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%90%D7%97%D7%90_%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%A8%D7%91)).

So it's seems that Rav Aha is not the son of Rav (ie Rabbi Abba bar Aybo, who was in 1st).

So, who is this "Rav" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In it's "לחקר שמות וכינויים בתלמוד", page 63, Rav Margolies explain that "Rav" was the name of his father, as there was other with this name, as "Rav Bar Sheva".